Best method for learning which accidentals to use in diatonic modulation

In this image I have taken a standard descending 5th sequence and elaborated it with neighbor chords and 7th chords. The figured basss shows some 43 chords leading to the next chord in the descending 5th progression. I have added accidentals to the first 2 such 43 chords .They are secondary dominants to the subdominant and to the mediant. My post is related to the thought process by which one is to arrive at what accidentals should be used to effect the modulation. Obviously some of the notes must be chromatically altered to create a dominant 43 else the diatonic versions while still sounding good don't lead as well as a V43 does. I have two thought processes which I am debating and there well could be others so please correct and add in your answers.

The first will be to memorize the accidentals to be modified based on the chord to which the temporary dominant leads. This is what I have used for the first two 43 chords. I know that any dominant leading to a sudominant chord will have a b7 and in the key of 2 flats that is Ab so I make A♮ into an A♭ to get my dominant chord. Similarly, the mediant will always take rasied scale degree 4 and 2 so C♮ becomes C♯ and E♭ becomes E♮.
The second method goes by memorizing intervals above the bass of the chord. So in the first 43 chord i would have to know what the intervals are above the bass note F and their quality. In this case, I had F,A,Bb,D. So a M3, P4 and M6. If I my intervals above the bass of all the 7th chord inversions (6/5 4/3 and 4/2) I will know that this is a Major 7th chord and since I need a dominant 7th chord I will need a m3 above the bass not a M3. So if I change that I once again have my dominant chord with an A♭.

Ok so those are the two ways I have thought about using but to be honest I don't know if I like the second but that might just be because I haven't learned all those intervals by heart of all the different 7th chord inversions so find it easier just to remember which accidentals lead to the diatonic chords in any key. They are always the same ones. So when leading to the supertonic, its a raised ^1, when leading to vi its a raised ^5 etc etc.
Which method do you use and are there any other methods that composers use?

Use the accidentals to fit the key (signature) of the key you modulate into or tonicize. Any chord or melodic segment that is altered from that target key signature should be spelled relative to the target key. For example, you you want to write an augmented sixth chord that modulates to another key, spell that augmented sixth chord according to the target key. Same for the variable ^6 and ^7 degrees in minor. This is your first method.
The second method seems like old figured bass thinking. That isn't necessarily a problem, but it's might seem more complicated. For your first 4/3 chord, the B♭7 chord going to E♭, you should make the figure 4/♭3 for just 4/♭ to reflect the A♭ accidental. You can figure out the spelling of modulating chords from figured bass, but if you're used to staff notation and key signatures, it might be difficult. Personally, I still need figured bass with some notation above to be sure I understand chromatic changes.

"but it might seem more complicated": this seems like the main reason for the success of Rameau's theory.
